# FullCalendar JSON Feed not working: my calendar doesn't put the data from the JSON feed onto my webpage

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, fullcalendar

Why doesn't my calendar put the data from the JSON feed onto my webpage?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: 'myfeed.php',
    header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
    eventSources: [

    // your event source
    {
        url: '/myfeed.php', // use the `url` property
        color: 'red',    // an option!
        textColor: 'black'  // an option!
    }
    // any other sources...
],
  eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?")) {
    }
else
{
    // remove calender, and post the info to page 
$.post("mybook.php", { idnumber: calEvent.id, remove: '1' } );
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', [calEvent.id]);
}
}
    });     
});
</script>
```

JSON Feed PHP Code

```
<?php    $arr = array('id' => '1', 'title' => 'Apples', 'start' => '1372530615', 'end' => '1372537615', 'allDay' => false);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Charles web debugger shows that the script is assessing the right page, and it has a response. But, my calendar does nothing. :( I thought it might be because I was using SSL, but I have tried both ways.

Reduced my code to

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: 'myfeed.php'
});     
});
</script>
```

JSON Feed Output

```
{"id":"1","title":"Apples","allDay":false,"start":"1372507615","end":"1372537615"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to put [ ] around my JSON Output.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `eventSources` if you are already using `events` property.

Answer (score 0):

I want to confirm the accepted answer above.  I have seen several such questions about events not showing up in FullCalendar, particularly JSON, and the solutions seem to be about syntax. You have to give FullCalendar EXACTLY what it wants to see, and documentation on that point is somewhat unclear. Expect a lot of trial and error.

Comment: Everything was correct, but my PHP output file did not have [ ] around the output which is incorrect JSON. I Should have serialized my array instead of manually creating the JSON output?

Answer (score 0):

I landed on this question with the same issue and did the following things to get it to work:

1. Make sure that there are square brackets [] at the end
2. Make sure that there are **no extra commas at the end** (this is what got me) - apparently it is ok with it when using a the paramenters inline, but when loading from JSON it has this issue
3. Use double quotes for both fiend and values.
4. I ended up rewriting my php to create an object array, load the values into the array, and then convert it into JSON (this took care of all the above JSON formatting issues)

My JSON output looked like:

```
[{"title":"Vishal","start":"2018-01-12 00:00:00","end":"2018-01-12 10:00:00"},{"title":"Vishal","start":"2018-01-14 14:00:00","end":"2018-01-14 15:00:00"}]
```

My PHP code looks like:

```
$data = array();

foreach($results as $run)
{

    $obj = (object) [
    'title' => $run->firstname,
    'start' => $run->startdatetime,
    'end' => $run->enddatetime
    ];

    $data[] = $obj;

}
echo json_encode($data);
```

I hope this helps.