# Fullcalendar does not render events loaded from .NET6 API

Tags: angular, .net-core, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am using FullCalendar version 5.5.0 and when I try loading events from my API, the events are not rendered. I have calendar options specified like this in my angular component.

```js
calendarOptions = {
   initialView: "dayGridMonth",
   weekends: false, //initial value

   dateClick: this.handleDateClick.bind(this),

   customButtons: {
     myCustomButton: {
       text: "custom!",
       click: () => {
         alert("clicked the custom button!");
       }
     }
   },
   headerToolbar: {
     left: "prev,next today myCustomButton",
     center: "title",
   },
   events: "https://localhost:5001/api/Events/Range"
 };
```

The request to my API works correctly, the URL looks like this

> api/Events/Range?start=2022-01-03T00:00:00+01:00&end=2022-02-12T00:00:00+01:00

When the request is fired by FullCalendar, the response is successful and it's body looks like this.

```json
[{"id":"string","start":"2022-01-23T13:39:17.596","end":"2022-01-23T13:39:17.596","title":"string","url":"string","classNames":"string","editable":true,"color":"string"}]
```

But this event is not the rendered in the calendar.

I tried searching on the web, in the documentation and also here, on stackoverflow. While it appears that people have a lot of similar problems, solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51996433/cannot-render-events-fullcalendar-with-json) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384065/fullcalendar-json-feed-not-working-my-calendar-doesnt-put-the-data-from-the-js) did not work for me.

Comment: If there are more details needed, please write a comment and I will provide them.

Comment: I am not sure if you can get the events only by url. At least when I tried I never managed to get it working. I did create a function that fetches the events from the API and returns an array with the event objects and that has worked for me. Although I do it in vanilla JS. It was like events: await attachEvents() where attachEvents returns an array of the event object.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed) it be possible, the fetching works, but the events are not displayed in the calendar after the fetch.

Comment: There is nothing [in the docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-parsing) about supporting date time strings with fractions of a second, in 3 decimal places.  Have you tried using a more standard date time string, without that?

Comment: @Don'tPanic this solved my problem. Can you perhaps change your comment into an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: @dodekja you're always allowed to answer your own question too, so you can show what specific code changes you had to make in your case to get it working. It's likely to be useful to others to know the exact code. That doesn't prevent Don't Panic from making a contributing answer as well, though.

Comment: The thing is, I didn't really change anything in the code, I just removed milliseconds from the datetime values.

Comment: Well you must have changed _something_ in order for it not to put those values in when it retrieves the data and generates the JSON...unless it's all just hard-coded on the server-side?

Comment: I was testing my application with swagger, so I just sent a POST request to my API, but without the millisecond part in both the start and end DateTimes. When I reloaded the calendar, the new event was rendered correctly.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, unless you've not described it clearly. Your request (`api/Events/Range?start=2022-01-03T00:00:00+01:00&end=2022-02-12T00:00:00+01:00` as per your question) doesn't contain a millisecond component, so you couldn't have removed anything from that. It's the dates in the _response_ from the API which contains the milliseconds. Changing that response output would require a change to the server-side code which generates the JSON.

Comment: @ADyson It might not make much sense, but the DateTime representation is an [ISO 8601 time string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) which can be defined both with and without the milliseconds. So when the milliseconds are not specified, or are equal to 0, the millisecond part is not added to the string. This might an overlooked detail in the implementation of FullCalendar, I'm not sure. But it works only without the milliseconds.

Comment: Yes, fullCalendar only works without the milliseconds. That's the part which is clear. So what _exactly_ did you do in order to remove the milliseconds from your JSON? Are you saying you simply removed them by hand in your database or something? Because if so, you'll need to consider how that data got there, and ensure you don't add any more data containing milliseconds into those columns in future.

Comment: Yes, I just added a new event that did not have the milliseconds, and deleted the old one.  But this was done through the API. However, when I tried to post this as an issue on github and tried to make an minimal example, I found out that it works with milliseconds specified in the [Standard with JSON feed example](https://fullcalendar.io/reduced-test-cases). Now I am not sure if it is a bug in the Angular implementation, or if there is just something weird going on on my side.

Comment: Yes you're right (https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/zYPxqLK?editors=001), I didn't know that sorry. So yeah maybe something weird with the Angular...perhaps raise a bug with a minimal example specifically using Angular

Comment: I'll do that as soon as possible.

Comment: @dodekja It's a bit of an odd half-answer, but OK, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an answer as suggested in the comments.  It may help but might only be part of the solution, see further discussion and investigation by @dodekja (OP) and @ADyson in the comments.

Though [the docs for date formats](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-parsing) supported by FullCalendar do say it should support (extended) ISO8601 strings, none of the examples or text mention date-time strings including milliseconds, like those in your feed:

```
... "start":"2022-01-23T13:39:17.596" ...
```

You pointed out that [ISO8601 strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) *can* optionally include milliseconds, however it seems
FullCalendar does not seem to support them - at least in the Angular implementation (see further investigation by @dodekja (OP) and @ADyson in the comments).